What are the origins of cryptographic security games/experiments?
I have seen some older papers with no security proofs whatsoever (eg. Chaum, 82), so it is clear that cryptographers have not always conducted their work with the kind of rigor that is more common today. What inspired this shift?
More precisely, what inspired the idea of presenting security definitions as games or experiments?
Of course, in hindsight it seems like an entirely obvious way to construct definitions, but how long have cryptographers done provable security through the use of security games? Who came up with the idea?
Note. I am familiar with the pitfalls of game-based security, and also with other types of security definitions. For the purpose of this question, I am interested only in game-based security.

The standard starting points for the foundations of formal game-based security definitions/proofs are:

Shoup: Sequences of games: a tool for taming complexity in security proofs
Bellare & Rogaway: Code-Based Game-Playing Proofs
and the Security of Triple Encryption

Below is a quote from the introduction of Bellare & Rogaway which provides some historical perspective:

What is the game-playing technique? One complication in any discussion about game-playing proofs is that the term means different things to different people. To some, a game-playing
proof in cryptography is any proof where one conceptualizes the adversary’s interaction with its
environment as a kind of game, the proof proceeding by stepwise refinement to that game. Viewed
in this way, game-playing proofs have their origin in the earliest hybrid arguments, which began
with Goldwasser and Micali [25] and Yao [50]. Bellare and Goldwasser provide an early example
of an intricate proof of this flavor, demonstrating the security of a signature scheme that uses
multiple cryptographic primitives [4]. In recent years Shoup has come to use such game-based
proofs extensively [1, 16–18, 43, 45, 46, 48], as have other authors.
We believe that game-playing proofs can be most effectively studied and systematized by imposing some discipline on the process and, in particular, regarding games as code. This viewpoint
begins in 1994 with Kilian and Rogaway [32].
Code-based game-playing soon became the favored
technique of Rogaway, who, along with coauthors, used it in many subsequent papers [6, 10, 12–14, 27, 28, 40–42]


[25] = Goldwasser & Micali: Probabilistic Encryption
[32] = Kilian & Rogaway: How to protect DES against exhaustive key search (an analysis of
DESX).
[50] = Yao: Theory and application of trapdoor functions


The definition of "Semantic Security" was in Goldwasser + Micali's "Probabilistic Encryption" in Crypto 84. Iirc they prove that semantic security (inability to efficiently compute non-trivial functions $f(m)$ of encrypted ciphertexts $\mathsf{Enc}(m)$) is equivalent to a notion similar to (probably the same as) IND-CPA security.
A similar definition to semantic security appears in prior papers of theirs (see Probabilistic Encryption &
How To Play Mental Poker Keeping Secret
All Partial Information, I think in FOCS 82), though without the connection to IND-CPA-type security. So it seems safe to say that sometime between 1982 and 1984 the idea of connecting inability to compute some function ("semantic security") was connected to inability to attain non-negligible advantage in some game.
That being said, the above is orthogonal to

cryptographers have not always conducted their work with the kind of rigor that is more common today

Even in the 1982 paper, Goldwasser and Micali state that (top of page 10)

Theorem 6 shows that inverting the function $E$ on the encrypted message is as hard as deciding quadratic residuosity ...

The statement of Theorem 6 is not self-contained. Still, provided their summary of it is accurate (there is no reason to think it is not), as early as 1982 there was a cryptosystem that achived an (admittedly weak, by contemporary standards) notion of provable (by contemporary standards) security, via a reduction to some independent problem ($\mathsf{QR}$).
